# Showing project on the same place using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I have hard time with jquery and positioning items that are hidden and must be shown. I have 2 White Boxes. Left Box is Client Box(with different names) and Right box(with different projects) is project box so Im trying according the name of the client from the left box when onClick to show his project on the right box and until this moment everything is working but the problem is when I click on the second user the projects that belong to the second user are shown under the projects which belongs to the first name(user). So I want to show every projects on the same LINE. I do not want to show them one under the other.

```
Here is link to jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/m2w3owkh/1/
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your code example doesn't match the scenario you are describing.

Comment: sorry, I fixed the link

Comment: Confuse about your question. Do you want to show only projects for the clicked user? FOr ex: If I clicked user 1 then it should show projects for user 1 and then when I clicked user 2 it will remove all projects for user 1 and show projects for user 2? Is it correct?

Comment: You have each "project" in a separate <li> element, this will cause them to be on separate lines.

Comment: yes I would to do this trick but the main idea is to show the projects on the same line. @DeepakBiswal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```js
$("#show1").click(function(){
        $(".project_1").toggle();
     $('.projectList>li>a>p').not('.project_1').hide();
    });

    $("#show2").click(function(){
        $(".project_2").toggle();
        $('.projectList>li>a>p').not('.project_2').hide();
    });

     $("#show3").click(function(){
        $(".project_3").toggle();
         $('.projectList>li>a>p').not('.project_3').hide();
    });

      $("#show4").click(function(){
        $(".project_4").toggle();
          $('.projectList>li>a>p').not('.project_4').hide();
    });
```

```css
.cprojectClients{ 
 position: relative;
 left: 40px;
 float: left;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width: 280px;
 height: 400px;
 z-index: 2;
 -webkit-box-shadow: -16px 2px 38px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: -16px 2px 38px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: -16px 2px 38px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 
}


.cprojectOffers{
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 right: 10px;
 top:10px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width: 280px;
 height: 400px;
 z-index: 1;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 16px 2px 38px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: 16px 2px 38px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: 16px 2px 38px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cprojectClients"> 
     <p>Client Name</p>
     
    <ul class="list">
      <li> 
       <h3 id="show1">Joe</h3>
        </li>

     <li>
         <h3 id="show2">John</h3>
     </li>
     <li>
      <h3 id="show3">Jason</h3>  
     </li>
     <li>
         <a href="javascript:;"><h3 id="show4">Jacob</h3></a>
     </li>
    </ul>

    </div><!--.cproject-clients--> 



    <div class="cprojectOffers"> 
     <p>Project Name</p>

     <ul class="projectList">
       <li> 
        <a href="javascript:;"><p style="display:none;" class="project_1">project_1.pdf</p></a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a href="javascript:;"><p style="display:none;" class="project_1">project_9.pdf</p></a> 
         </li>
      <li>
         <a href="javascript:;"><p style="display:none;" class="project_2">project_2.pdf</p></a> 
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="javascript:;"><p style="display:none;" class="project_3">project_3.pdf</p></a> 
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="javascript:;"><p style="display:none;" class="project_4">project_4.pdf</p></a> 
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="javascript:;"><p style="display:none;" class="project_4">project_5.pdf</p></a> 
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="javascript:;"><p style="display:none;" class="project_4">project_6.pdf</p></a> 
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="javascript:;"><p style="display:none;" class="project_4">project_7.pdf</p></a> 
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="javascript:;"><p style="display:none;" class="project_4">project_8.pdf</p></a> 
      </li>


     </ul>
    </div><!--.cproject-offers-->
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest restructuring the way this works. Right now you have all the projects listed within the same ul which will mean that when you hide projects from other clients, there will be gaps above and below the currently selected client's projects.

One way to resolve this would be to create a different `ul` for each group of projects and then show and hide those on click.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#show1").click(function(){
        $(".project").hide();
        $(".project_1").toggle();
    });

    $("#show2").click(function(){
        $(".project").hide();
        $(".project_2").toggle();
    });

     $("#show3").click(function(){
         $(".project").hide();
        $(".project_3").toggle();
    });

      $("#show4").click(function(){
        $(".project").hide();
        $(".project_4").toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.cprojectClients{ 
 position: relative;
 left: 40px;
 float: left;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width: 280px;
 height: 400px;
 z-index: 2;
 -webkit-box-shadow: -16px 2px 38px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: -16px 2px 38px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: -16px 2px 38px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 
}


.cprojectOffers{
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 right: 10px;
 top:10px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width: 280px;
 height: 400px;
 z-index: 1;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 16px 2px 38px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: 16px 2px 38px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: 16px 2px 38px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.project {
    display:none;
}

.list h3 {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cprojectClients"> 
 <p>Client Name</p>

 <ul class="list">
  <li> 
   <h3 id="show1">Joe</h3>
  </li>
  <li>
   <h3 id="show2">John</h3>
  </li>
  <li>
   <h3 id="show3">Jason</h3>  
  </li>
  <li>
   <h3 id="show4">Jacob</h3>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div><!--.cproject-clients-->

<div class="cprojectOffers"> 
 <p>Project Name</p>

 <ul class="project project_1">
  <li> 
   <a><p>project_1.pdf</p></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a><p>project_9.pdf</p></a> 
  </li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="project project_2">
  <li>
   <a><p>project_2.pdf</p></a> 
  </li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="project project_3">
  <li>
   <a><p>project_3.pdf</p></a> 
  </li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="project project_4">
  <li>
   <a><p>project_4.pdf</p></a> 
  </li>
  <li>
   <a><p>project_5.pdf</p></a> 
  </li>
  <li>
   <a><p>project_6.pdf</p></a> 
  </li>
  <li>
   <a><p>project_7.pdf</p></a> 
  </li>
  <li>
   <a><p>project_8.pdf</p></a> 
  </li>
 </ul>
</div><!--.cproject-offers-->
```

You can clean it up even more than this and structure it in a way that you can reuse the same jQuery function to do this for any number of clients/projects without having to add a new click function every time you add a new client, but this should get you started.